# Kubernetes v1.12 Problems with kubectl exec

Tags: kubernetes, exec, kubectl

I’ve been learning about Kubernetes using Kelsey Hightower’s excellent kubernetes-the-hard-way-guide.

Using this guide I’ve installed v1.12 on GCE. Everything works perfectly apart from kubectl exec:

```
$ kubectl exec -it shell-demo – /bin/bash --kubeconfig=/root/certsconfigs/admin.kubeconfig
error: unable to upgrade connection: Forbidden (user=kubernetes, verb=create, resource=nodes, subresource=proxy)
```

Note that I have set `KUBECONFIG=/root/certsconfigs/admin.kubeconfig`.

Apart from exec all other kubectl functions work as expected with this `admin.kubeconfig` file, so from that I deduce it valid for use with my cluster.

I’m pretty sure I have made a beginners mistake somewhere, but if somebody could advise where I have gone away, I should be most grateful.

TIA

Shaun

I have double checked that no `.kube/config` file exists anywhere on my master controller:

```
root@controller-1:/root/deployment/kubernetes# kubectl get pods
NAME READY STATUS
shell-demo 1/1 Running 0 23m
```

Here is the output with -v8:

```
root@controller-1:/root/deployment/kubernetes# kubectl -v8 exec -it shell-demo – /bin/bash
I1118 15:18:16.898428 11117 loader.go:359] Config loaded from file /root/certsconfigs/admin.kubeconfig
I1118 15:18:16.899531 11117 loader.go:359] Config loaded from file /root/certsconfigs/admin.kubeconfig
I1118 15:18:16.900611 11117 loader.go:359] Config loaded from file /root/certsconfigs/admin.kubeconfig
I1118 15:18:16.902851 11117 round_trippers.go:383] GET ://127.0.0.1:6443/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/shell-demo
I1118 15:18:16.902946 11117 round_trippers.go:390] Request Headers:
I1118 15:18:16.903016 11117 round_trippers.go:393] Accept: application/json, /
I1118 15:18:16.903091 11117 round_trippers.go:393] User-Agent: kubectl/v1.12.0 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/0ed3388
I1118 15:18:16.918699 11117 round_trippers.go:408] Response Status: 200 OK in 15 milliseconds
I1118 15:18:16.918833 11117 round_trippers.go:411] Response Headers:
I1118 15:18:16.918905 11117 round_trippers.go:414] Content-Type: application/json
I1118 15:18:16.918974 11117 round_trippers.go:414] Content-Length: 2176
I1118 15:18:16.919053 11117 round_trippers.go:414] Date: Sun, 18 Nov 2018 15:18:16 GMT
I1118 15:18:16.919218 11117 request.go:942] Response Body: {“kind”:“Pod”,“apiVersion”:“v1”,“metadata”:{“name”:“shell-demo”,“namespace”:“default”,“selfLink”:"/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/shell-demo",“uid”:“99f320f8-eb42-11e8-a053-42010af0000b”,“resourceVersion”:“13213”,“creationTimestamp”:“2018-11-18T14:59:51Z”},“spec”:{“volumes”:[{“name”:“shared-data”,“emptyDir”:{}},{“name”:“default-token-djprb”,“secret”:{“secretName”:“default-token-djprb”,“defaultMode”:420}}],“containers”:[{“name”:“nginx”,“image”:“nginx”,“resources”:{},“volumeMounts”:[{“name”:“shared-data”,“mountPath”:"/usr/share/nginx/html"},{“name”:“default-token-djprb”,“readOnly”:true,“mountPath”:"/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount"}],“terminationMessagePath”:"/dev/termination-log",“terminationMessagePolicy”:“File”,“imagePullPolicy”:“Always”}],“restartPolicy”:“Always”,“terminationGracePeriodSeconds”:30,“dnsPolicy”:“ClusterFirst”,“serviceAccountName”:“default”,“serviceAccount”:“default”,“nodeName”:“worker-1”,“securityContext”:{},“schedulerName”:“default-scheduler”,“tolerations”:[{“key”:"node.kubernet [truncated 1152 chars]
I1118 15:18:16.925240 11117 round_trippers.go:383] POST …
error: unable to upgrade connection: Forbidden (user=kubernetes, verb=create, resource=nodes, subresource=proxy)
```

Comment: Have you tried to add `--kubelet-client-certificate` and `--kubelet-client-key` flags to `kube-apiserver` as @Prafull Ladha mentioned in his answer?

Answer (score 2):

According to your logs,the connection between kubectl and the apiserver is fine, and is being authenticated correctly.

To satisfy an exec request, the apiserver contacts the kubelet running the pod, and that connection is what is being forbidden.

Your kubelet is configured to authenticate/authorize requests, and the apiserver credential is not authorized to make the exec request against the kubelet's API.

Based on the forbidden message, your apiserver is authenticating as the "kubernetes" user to the kubelet.

You can grant that user full permissions to the kubelet API with the following command:

`kubectl create clusterrolebinding apiserver-kubelet-admin --user=kubernetes --clusterrole=system:kubelet-api-admin`

See the following docs for more information

> https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kubelet-authentication-authorization/#overview
>
> https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#other-component-roles